# How to create a RadioButton without a content (uwp,xaml,c#)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, radio-button

I want to create a custom control with only a radiobutton and no content. is there a function that let cancel/remove the content part, should i use templated control to modify the template (and can i do that ?).

Comment: Had you tagged what technology you are using (via tags) then someone might be able to help you. Please [edit] your questions and add the appropriate tags

Comment: Why do you need to create a custom control to do this? Adding a RadioButton via xaml without putting anything in the `Content` property gives the desired result (just the circular Radiobutton part, no text)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `RadioButton` without a content is very easy:

```
<RadioButton />
```

If you want to remove the content completely, you can modify the default style (see the [default style here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299147.aspx)):

```
...  
    </Grid>
    <!-- comment out or delete the Content Presenter -->
    <!-- <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                      TextWrapping="Wrap" /> -->
  </Grid>
...
```